# WSO2 IS worker nodes not able to join 2 WSO2 ELBs

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been able to set up a WSO2 IS cluster consisting of 1 management node and 2 worker nodes.
Both the worker nodes are fronted with a WSO2 ELB.

I Have then tried to set up another WSO2 ELB fronting the worker nodes and configured the extra ELB as part of members in axis2.xml of the worker nodes.

But the worker is only able to join 1 ELB and not both at the same time.

Snapshot of Logs on ELB
Successfully joined:

> TID: [0] [ELB] [2014-08-07 05:21:22,113]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent} -  Member joined [180045d4-6575-47cf-a879-6061395a19d9]: / {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent}
>   TID: [0] [ELB] [2014-08-07 05:21:25,165]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils} -  Added member: Host:, Remote Host:null, Port: 4012, HTTP:9765, HTTPS:9445, Domain: , Sub-domain:worker, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils}
>   TID: [0] [ELB] [2014-08-07 05:21:25,166]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent} -  Application member Host:, Remote Host:null, Port: 4012, HTTP:9765, HTTPS:9445, Domain: , Sub-domain:worker, Active:true joined application cluster {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent}
>    Unsuccessful:
>   TID: [0] [ELB] [2014-08-07 05:21:22,113]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent} -  Member joined [180045d4-6575-47cf-a879-6061395a19d9]: / {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent}

However, I don’t see the “Added member” logs.

Which ELB the worker will join is completely random (have not been able to find any pattern).

Has anybody been able to get such a topology working?

According to this link: http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/09/make-wso2-elb-highly-available-through-aws-elb/
Setup should work.

Have tried with WSO2 ELB 2.0.3 ( as per the link) but no luck. Neither with trying to cluster the 2 ELBs

Versions:
WSO2 ELB: 2.1.1
WSO2 IS: 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

It is better, If you can use the newest document on this which can be found at [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Identity+Server). It clearly explains how you can use WSO2IS with WSO2ELB.  However, please note that WSO2IS has not a concept of worker/manager. It is only applicable to service/web hosting product like ESB and App server. Identity Server can only have manager nodes. So You can deploy it in a cluster very easily. If you want to get more and clear understanding on clustering the Identity Server product, you can read [this](http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/10/how-to-is-clustering-identity-server/) article. I suggest that, if you do not need elastic capabilities it is fine to use Load balancer like Apache HTTPD, Ngix and etc to load balance the Identity server cluster. They can work with Identity Server perfectly and would be more faster than ELB. I am personally preferred them rather than using WSO2 ELB. If you like to configure with Apache HTTPD server, you can get more information from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/10/load-balancing-for-identity-server-nodes-using-apache-http-server/) as well.